# Почему возвращается NaN?

Tags: javascript

```
let j;
for(let i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
  console.log(i);
  j += i;
}

console.log(j);
```

Answer (score 7):

Потому что когда пишешь `let j;` - не значит, что  `j` инициализирован нулем по умолчанию. Он — `undefined`. А что будет если складывать `undefined` с числом?